# Resetting NSMutableAttributedString string is not applying its attributes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
UIFont *keyFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-bold" size:16];
NSDictionary *keyFontDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:keyFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSMutableAttributedString *titleAttrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"" attributes:keyFontDict];

NSString *str = @"ABC";
[titleAttrStr.mutableString setString:str];
```

if I set the above attributed string the font is not being applied.
If I do in below format I am able to get the font.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *titleAttrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str attributes:keyFontDict];
```

I want to create only once & use the attributedString by reseting the string.

Comment: Use `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:`?

Comment: What is `EMPTY_STR` and what value it contains?

Comment: Its just empty string updated

Comment: I want to change complete string instead of characters

Comment: font name is wrong please add correct font name @"Roboto-Bold"

Answer (score 1):

If you use non-empty string at the moment when you create an object, it will work as expected:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *titleAttrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" " attributes:keyFontDict];
```

Comment: Is it documented? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be better to have a factory function or something to build you attributed string with some text?

```
- (NSAttributedString *)attributedTextWithString:(NSString *) string {
    UIFont *keyFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-bold" size:16];
    // make sure to use modern Objective-C syntax too...
    NSDictionary *keyFontDict = @{NSFontAttributeName: keyFont};
    return [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:keyFontDict];
}
```

Creating the string is then just a case of calling that function with the new string value.

And you still only have one place that actually creates the attributed string (if you need to change it etc...).

Creating attributed strings isn't expensive enough to warrant only creating them once and updating them. Just create it from fresh each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the old string, and reapply the attributes. This is still expensive, but at least you do not need to reallocate a `NSAttributedString`.

```
[titleAttrStr replaceCharactersInRange:NSRangeFromString(titleAttrStr.string) withString:@"someNewStrig"];
[titleAttrStr setAttributes:keyFontDict range:NSRangeFromString(titleAttrStr.string)];
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use this code My code will help you

```
NSString *strLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"ABC",@"DEF"];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strLocation];
[attributedText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName : @"Roboto-Bold" size : 16] range:NSMakeRange(0, [strLocation length])];
attributedText = [self addFont:attributedText toText:@"ABC"];
lblQue.attributedText = attributedText;

- (NSMutableAttributedString *)addFont:(NSMutableAttributedString *)attributedString toText:(NSString *)subString {
     NSRange substriingRange = [[attributedString string] rangeOfString:subString];
     [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:substriingRange]; //TextColor
     [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName : @"Roboto-Bold" size : 16] range:substriingRange]; //TextFont
     return attributedString;
}
```